# Evaluating a function at compile time with Template Haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I am writing a simple HashString class, which is just a string and its hash:

```
data HashString = HashString Int    -- ^ hash
                             T.Text -- ^ string!
```

Now I'm trying to generate these at compile time with something like:

```
$(hString "hello, world") :: HashString
```

I want the hash, and the text packing to happen at compile time. How do I do this?

Here's what I've tried so far, but I'm not sure if its right, nor am I sure it does everything at compile time:

```
hString :: String -> Q Exp
hString s = [| HashString (hash $ T.pack s) (T.pack s) |]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way you've written your code, no evaluation will happen at compile-time. When you quote a Haskell expression with `[| ... |]`, the quoted code/AST is inserted where you apply it without any evaluation, so writing:

```
$(hString "hello, world")
```

is exactly the same as writing:

```
let s = "hello, world" in HashString (hash $ T.pack s) (T.pack s)
```

But think about it like this: you use `[| ... |]` to quote an expression to be inserted later, and you generate code at compile-time with `$(...)`. So, if you include some code `$(foo)` in a quoted expression `bla = [| bar $(foo) |]`, doing `$(bla)` will generate the code `bar $(foo)`, which in turn will evaluate `foo` at compile time. Also, to take a value that you generate at compile time and generate an expression from it, you use the [`lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/latest/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:lift) function. So, what you want to do is this:

```
import Data.String (fromString)
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

hString s = [| HashString $(lift . hash . T.pack $ s) (fromString s) |]
```

This evaluates the hash function at compile time, since the inner splice is resolved after the outer splice was resolved. By the way, using `fromString` from `Data.String` is the generic way of constructing some `OverloadedString` data type from a `String`.

Also, you should consider making a quasi-quoter for your `HashString` interface. Using quasi-quoters is more natural than manually calling splice functions (And you've already used them; the nameless `[| ... |]` quoter quotes Haskell expressions).

You would create a quasiquoter like this:

```
import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote

hstr =
  QuasiQuoter
  { quoteExp = hString -- Convenient: You already have this function
  , quotePat = undefined
  , quoteType = undefined
  , quoteDec = undefined
  }
```

This would let you write `HashString`s with this syntax:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
myHashString = [hstr|hello, world|]
```